# Can jQuery clearInterval keep a background image set by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a image as a background image in the CSS. There are three images that I am cycling through. The last one is what I want to keep after cycling through them, how can I keep the last image and clear the interval? Or is there a better way to write the jQuery without setInterval?

I know enough of this stuff to get in trouble. Thanks for your help!

```
#top {
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url("/sites/default/files/pictures/hero_image12.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Then I am using this jQuery to run through the images.

```
var imageArray = [
  '/sites/default/files/pictures/hero_image12.png',
  '/sites/default/files/pictures/hero_image_2.jpg',
  '/sites/default/files/pictures/hero_image_3.jpg'
]
var itemInterval = 6000,
  numberOfItems = 3,
  currentItem = 1;

function changeImage() {
  $('#top').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageArray[currentItem] + ')');
  if (currentItem === numberOfItems - 1) {
    currentItem = 0;
  } else {
    currentItem++
  }
}
var slide = setInterval(function() {
  changeImage();
}, itemInterval)
```

Comment: Not exactly clear on the issue, but maybe this will help? I changed the image URLs, changed the `#top` height, and set `background-size` to `contain` for testing. It starts on the image defined in CSS, moves through three other images in the array, then clears the interval when it hits the last image: http://jsfiddle.net/uo14285b/

Comment: Many thanks! That code worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` so that instead of setting `currentItem` back to `0` when it reaches the end, it simply clears the interval.

```
function changeImage() {
  $('#top').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageArray[currentItem] + ')');
  if (currentItem === numberOfItems - 1) {
    clearInterval(slide);
  } else {
    currentItem++
  }
}
```